# @Transactional rollback in loop

Tags: java, spring, loops, spring-transactions

I have some problem with rollback transaction when using @Transactional. I have the following code:

```
@Transactional
public class A{

    @Resource
    Object obj;

    public void insertMultiTable(){
        for(Item item:items){
            try{
                obj.insertTableA();
                obj.insertTableB();
            } catch(Exception e){
                // do somethings...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, i will do insertTableA and insertTableB, my process are success when both finish. I had first and second time is success. But in third, insertTableB will throw Exception, and i just want rollback only this loop with first and second times had been insert in database. How i can do it? Please help...

Answer (score 6):

Move your logic to another service and mark it with `@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)`

It will make each loop transaction is independent. (IE: Third loop throw exception will only rollback the third loop, leave the first and second loop result committed)

```
public class SubA {
    @Resource
    Object obj;

    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
    public void insert(Item i) {
           try{
                obj.insertTableA();
                obj.insertTableB();
            } catch(Exception e){
                // do somethings...
            }
    }
}
```

Now call this service in your `A` class

```
@Transactional
public class A{

    @Resource
    SubA subA;

    public void insertMultiTable(){
        for(Item item:items){
            subA.insert(item);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks you for your answer. It's very helpful!!