# Manual transactional rollback bounds to an individual iteration in a forEach loop in Spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, transactions

I'm trying to update a few columns in a table and the updation happens inside a `forEach`.

I want to handle each iteration as an individual transaction and any rollback inside the forEach should only rollback on the transactions that occurred on the specific iteration (not all previous iterations).

Moreover, I don't want an exception to trigger the rollback. Rather, it has to be triggered programmatically. For that, I'm making use of this - `TransactionInterceptor.currentTransactionStatus().setRollbackOnly();`

This is what I tried so far:

```
@Service
public class MyService {
    @Transactional
    public void processLabResults() {
        arrayList.forEach(i -> {
            proccessDiagnosis();
        });
    }

    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
    proccessDiagnosis() {
        boolean isDispositionUpdated = updateDisposition(); // calls JPA Repository to update
        if(isUpdated) {
            boolean isSomethingElseUpdated = updatedSomethingElse(); // calls JPA Repository to update
            if(!isSomethingElseUpdated) {
                TransactionInterceptor.currentTransactionStatus().setRollbackOnly(); //Should rollback only the transactions that happened in the current iteration
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If I executed the above, it rolls back all the previous transactions that are not part of the current iteration as well. If I remove `@ Transactional` annotation from the `processLabResults` method, I'm getting `No transaction aspect-managed TransactionStatus in scope`  error and no rollback happens.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50821337/10150468) answer helps me resolve the issue. I moved the `proccessDiagnosis()` function to a different service file.

Service.java

```
@Service
public class MyService {

    @AutoWired
    AnotherService anotherService;

    @Transactional
    public void processLabResults() {
        arrayList.forEach(i -> {
            anotherService.proccessDiagnosis();
        });
    }
}
```

AnotherService.java

```
@Service
public class AnotherService {
    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
    public void proccessDiagnosis() {
        boolean isDispositionUpdated = updateDisposition(); // calls JPA Repository to update
        if(isUpdated) {
            boolean isSomethingElseUpdated = updatedSomethingElse(); // calls JPA Repository to update
            if(!isSomethingElseUpdated) {
                TransactionInterceptor.currentTransactionStatus().setRollbackOnly(); //Should rollback only the transactions that happened in the current iteration
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If there is an exception in proccessDiagnosis method, then I want to catch the exception, save the exception data in some database table and then rollback the transaction for the data which was to be persisted in try block.